# Trouble sending an ajax request to Riot API

Tags: javascript, ajax, riot-games-api

```
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Sample Page</title>
  <script>
      var summonername = "TraversTT"
      var api_key1= "******"
      var headers1 = {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Origin': "https://developer.riotgames.com",
          'Accept-Charset': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
          'X-Riot-Token': "*****",
          'Accept-Language': "en-US,en;q=0.9",
          'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36',
      }
      var settings = {
       "async": true,
       "type": "POST",
       "url": "https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/"+summonername+"?api_key="+api_key1,
       "headers": headers1,
       "dataType": 'json',
       "data": 'dataTest',
     };
  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
       console.log(response);
     });
```

I am getting constant errors connecting to this API and getting a response other than:

> jquery.min.js:4 Refused to set unsafe header "Origin"
>      send @ jquery.min.js:4
>      ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
>      (anonymous) @ Riot dDragon access sample2.html:26
>      jquery.min.js:4 Refused to set unsafe header "Accept-Charset"
>      send @ jquery.min.js:4
>      ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
>      (anonymous) @ Riot dDragon access sample2.html:26
>      jquery.min.js:4 Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"
>      send @ jquery.min.js:4
>      ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
>      (anonymous) @ Riot dDragon access sample2.html:26
>      2jquery.min.js:4 OPTIONS https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by- 
>     name/TraversTT?api_key=RGAPI-1ed86c58-2eee-4e6c-85d4-3bead97e4d3b 405 (Method Not 
>      Allowed)
>      send @ jquery.min.js:4
>      ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
>      (anonymous) @ Riot dDragon access sample2.html:26
>      Riot dDragon access sample2.html:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 
>      'https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/TraversTT? 
>      api_key=RGAPI-1ed86c58-2eee-4e6c-85d4-3bead97e4d3b' from origin 'null' has been blocked 
>      by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 
>      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I've been playing with different ways of doing this today for like 6 hours so any help available would be amazing.

Comment: could you link to the documentation for the api. the one i found, it seems like there is no post endpoint: https://developer.riotgames.com/apis#summoner-v4. It also looks like you're wrongly setting some headers.

Comment: @c_ogoo Im unsure what other documentation you are looking for so far what you posted is all I have been using for myself:

If I run that using my ID I get: https://justpaste.it/2v8x2

Answer (score 0):

According to the api docs, your code should be something like this:

```js
<script>
  var summonername = "TraversTT";
  var api_key1= "RGAPI-1ed86c58-2eee-4e6c-85d4-3bead97e4d3b";
  var headers1 = {
    'X-Riot-Token': "RGAPI-1ed86c58-2eee-4e6c-85d4-3bead97e4d3b",
  }
  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "type": "GET",
    "url": "https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/"+summonername+"?api_key="+api_key1,
    "headers": headers1,
  };
  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
</script>
```

There are different types of HTTP requests; GET, POST, PUT, etc... You were using `POST` but that endpoint only supports `GET` and you were setting some headers that are typically response headers.

Unfortunately there is a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue on this endpoint, so your browser will not be able to access it via your browser.

You can try this `cUrl` in your terminal to see the response (copy and paste this into your terminal):

```
curl 'https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/TraversTT?api_key=RGAPI-1ed86c58-2eee-4e6c-85d4-3bead97e4d3b' -X OPTIONS -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: GET' -H 'Origin: https://js-9vpefs.stackblitz.io' -H 'Referer: https://js-9vpefs.stackblitz.io/' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-riot-token' --compressed
```

**Note**

I will suggest never to post your API key (`'X-Riot-Token': "RGAPI-1ed86c58-2eee-4e6c-85d4-3bead97e4d3b"`) on a public forum.

Comment: Ah thank you so much, so basically I cant run this in a browser is what your saying?

Also about the code: thank you, i was watching it for mis-use and have already changed it!

Comment: yes, though you may be able to after you do this: https://developer.riotgames.com/docs/portal